# Trigonometry Question. Area of a roof

Tags: trigonometry

[image]

I really can't figure out how to set up the diagram for this question.

I think it is a triangle with a 25 deg slope with heigth 8 m and with 15 m. Please tell me if I am correct. The correct answer is 132.45 m^2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The shingles are on the pale orange surface.

Comment: Amusingly, if we swap the "15 m" and "8 m" labels, we get the same area of shingles, so we can be sloppy about "length" and "width".

Answer (score 0):

Projection of $ 15\times 8= 120 $ sq. meters will come from slanted area $ 120/ \cos  25^{\circ}=132.45$ square meters.

It is like the shadow of roof when sun is up right overhead. Slant roof /Ceiling is shingled.

[image]

Comment: Hi there, Can you explain how the diagram looks like. I still in grade 11

Comment: A rough hand-sketch added.